# CSS selector targeting ordered list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target ol.sc-tracklist from within the following markup

```
<ul id="sc-track-list">
<li class="sc-track format-audio">
<div class="sc-player">
<ol class="sc-artwork-list">
<li class="sc-time-indicators">
<span class="sc-position">0.00</span>
 ¦
 <span class="sc-duration">2.38</span>
</li>
<li class="sc-controls">
<a class="sc-play" href="#play">4</a>
 <a class="sc-pause" href="#pause">5</a>
</li>
<li class="sc-track-artwork active">
<div class="sc-no-artwork"> 
</li>
</ol>
<ol class="sc-trackslist">
<li class="sc-info">
<h3 class="sc-track-title">
<a href="http://soundcloud.com/jillian02/gently">Gently</a>
<a class="sc-info-toggle button" href="#info">
more
<span class="icon">i</span>
</a>
</h3>
<div class="sc-more-info">
<h4>
 by
 <a href="http://soundcloud.com/jillian02">Jill Owen</a>
 </h4>
 <p class="remove-bottom">solo piano music</p>
 </div>
 <footer></footer>
 </li>
 <li class="active">
 <span class="sc-track-state"></span>
 <a href="http://soundcloud.com/jillian02/gently">Gently</a>
 <a href="null">
 <span>Buy</span>
 <span class="icon">}</span>
 </a>
 </li> 
 </ol>
 </div>
 <div class="meta">
 <p>
 <a class="spch-bub-inside" href="#">
 <span class="point"></span>
 <em>23</em>
 </a>
 </p> 
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

I've tryed

```
.sc-track.format-audio .sc-player .sc-tracklist
```

and

```
.sc-track.format-audio div.sc-player ol.sc-tracklist
```

But no joy.

The content is generated dynamically from a jquery json response I wonder if that has any bearing.

Any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: A `div` is ***not*** a valid child of a `ul` or `ol`, if you must use a `div` within a list place it inside an `li` element (the ***only*** valid child of a `ul` or `ol`).

Comment: Thanks David I can see the html structure is a little poor. Does this effect the css specificity though?

Comment: Yeah, it should; browsers tend to restructure broken html to make the DOM valid (or make their best effort at making it valid). How they handle this is often unspecified, and unpredictable. It may, or may not, involve moving nodes from one place to another, with the consequences of making your CSS selectors no longer sufficiently specific, or accurate.

Comment: Good to know, I'll try to clean things up a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is not well formed. Move this:

```
<div class="meta">
```

Out of the `<li></li>`.

Or if it should be there, close it:

```
 <div class="meta"></div>
```

Also, the `<ol>` elements should be closed as well.

*EDIT:* This works for me (see in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JPQFt/)):

### CSS:

```
li.sc-track.format-audio ol.sc-trackslist {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <li class="sc-track format-audio">
            <div class="sc-player">
                <ol class="sc-artwork-list"></ol>
                <ol class="sc-trackslist">
                    <li>SC TRACKLIST</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="meta"></div>
        </li>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Behrang thanks for your answer. I've updated the html. I wonder if you would mind going over it? Many thanks. James.

Comment: James, your element's class name is trackSlist (with s) but your selector is tracklist.

Comment: BTW did you follow a special process to catch that mistake? Is there  a method I can use so as to avoid those kinds of mistakes? Thanks again

Comment: No I didn't use any tools or processes, just noticed it. There's a tool that shows unused selectors on a page that might be useful though: http://www.sitepointstatic.com/dustmeselectors/. Other similar tools should also be available. Process wise, you can delete your CSS rules, and rebuild your rules by copy and pasting the class names from the HTML to your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

First modify and make sure your HTML is W3C compliant.

For `li` tag, class is specified as `sc-track format-audio`

To target a specific tag, you can target directly with that tag ID or class name.

Example:

`.sc-trackslist`

OR

`.format-audio .sc-trackslist`

OR

`.sc-track .sc-trackslist`

In some cases, you need to target as follows:-

`#parentID .2ndChildClass .1stChildClass`